# how to use AVCaptureSession to read a video from a file?

Tags: ios, opencv, video-processing

I am writing an app that does some real-time video processing using an `AVCaptureSession` with a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` as output and an `AVCaptureDeviceInput` with the video file (it no longer needs to be in real-time) as input.

Is it possible to use the video file as in input to the `AVCaptureSession` instead of the camera? 
If it is not possible, what is the best method to process a video file using video capture of `opencv on iOS` (either simultaneously or sequentially)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to the raw video file frames (from your `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`), you can convert each frame to a `cv::Mat` object (a opencv matrix, representing an image). Then do your image processing on each individual frame.

Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html
for a real time example using the camera; you can convert your UIImage to a `cv::Mat` using `cvMatFromUIImage`.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out it's not *too* difficult to do. The basic outline is:

1. Create a `cv::VideoCapture` to read from a file
2. Create a `CALayer` to receive and display each frame.
3. Run a method at a given rate that reads and processes each frame.
4. Once done processing, convert each `cv::Mat` to a `CGImageRef` and display it on the `CALayer`.

The actual implementation is as follows:

**Step 1: Create cv::VideoCapture**

```
std::string filename = "/Path/To/Video/File";
capture = cv::VideoCapture(filename);
if(!capture.isOpened()) NSLog(@"Could not open file.mov");
```

**Step 2: Create the Output CALayer**

```
self.previewLayer = [CALayer layer];
self.previewLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.previewLayer];
```

**Step 3: Create Processing Loop w/ GCD**

```
int kFPS = 30;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("timer", 0);
self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, dispatch_walltime(NULL, 0), (1/kFPS) * NSEC_PER_SEC, (0.5/kFPS) * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self processNextFrame];
    });
});

dispatch_resume(self.timer);
```

**Step 4: Processing Method**

```
-(void)processNextFrame {
    /* Read */
    cv::Mat frame;
    capture.read(frame);

    /* Process */
    ...

    /* Convert and Output to CALayer*/
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGB);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:frame.data
                              length:frame.elemSize()*frame.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = (frame.elemSize() == 3) ? kCGImageAlphaNone : kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef) data);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(frame.cols,
                                        frame.rows,
                                        8,
                                        8 * frame.elemSize(),
                                        frame.step[0],
                                        colorSpace,
                                        bitmapInfo,
                                        provider,
                                        NULL,
                                        false,
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

    self.previewLayer.contents = (__bridge id)imageRef;

    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the pasawaya solution ... the previewLayer was not refreshed ... I found where the problem came from :

In Step 4, replace :

```
self.previewLayer.contents = (__bridge id)imageRef;
```

With :

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayFrame:) withObject:(__bridge id)imageRef waitUntilDone:YES];
```

And add :

```
- (void)displayFrame:(CGImageRef)frame {
    _previewLayer.contents = (__bridge id)frame;
    [CATransaction flush];
}
```

Hope this help !